# Delegate Method Not Called - Google Turn-based Match Delegate

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, delegates, google-play-games

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a turn-based game with auto-match using the iOS Google Play SDK, and the GPGTurnBasedMatchDelegate does not seem to be working properly. Here is my situation:

1. Player 1 starts an auto-match game and takes turn
2. Player 2 joins the auto-match game and takes turn
3. Nothing happens...From everything that I have read, the following method should get called:

   ```
   -(void)didReceiveTurnEventForMatch:(GPGTurnBasedMatch *)match participant:(GPGTurnBasedParticipant *)participant fromPushNotification:(BOOL)fromPushNotification
   ```

The only time that this method gets called is when I show all the current matches with:

```
[GPGManager sharedInstance].statusDelegate = self;
[[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentTurnBasedMatchList];
```

The way my code is structured is that I have a GameManager singleton that is set as the delegate in the init method and includes the "didReceiveTurnEventForMatch" method.

```
-(instancetype) init {
    if (self = [super init]){
        [GPGManager sharedInstance].statusDelegate = self;
        [GPGManager sharedInstance].turnBasedMatchDelegate = self;
        self.isSilentlySigningIn = [[GPGManager sharedInstance] signInWithClientID:kClientID silently:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)didReceiveTurnEventForMatch:(GPGTurnBasedMatch *)match participant:(GPGTurnBasedParticipant *)participant fromPushNotification:(BOOL)fromPushNotification {
    NSLog(@"Hooray! Received an event in a match! %@", match);
}
```

**Question:**
Am I missing something here? Should I expect this delegate method to work differently?

Looks like Android had a similar issue: [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/158)

Comment: Is your app enabled to receive push notification? Also, did you implement the `didReceiveTurnBasedInviteForMatch` delegate method first? [This documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/turnbasedMultiplayer#handling_notifications) has suggested implementations in your app for handling notifications for turn-based multiplayer events. Or, you can try out the [sample project](https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples/tree/master/TBMPSkeleton) in GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I already had the delegate method implemented, so after enabling push notifications it started getting called. One thing that I found interesting is that you can make the incoming push notification silent to the user and handle the notification internally. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.